# Lifetime of an fstream object in a custom File Class

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm making an File class that uses `fstream` to read/write to a file. I have no issues in terms of functionality but rather in best practice regarding the lifetime of the `fstream` object.

Is it better to have an `fstream` object stored as a member variable that gets created for each new `File(path)`, and use that `fstream` over the lifetime of each File instance?

Or, for each individual function that I can call on a File instance (`readBytes()`, `writeBytes()`, `exists()`, `isDirectory()`, etc.), should I declare a local `ifstream/ofstream`, do what needs to be done, and, when the function exists, they go out of scope and are auto-closed?

In the first case, I fear that if I have many many files "open" there will be a penalty for having that many streams active at the same time.

In the second case, it just seems inefficient to continually create and destroy `fstream` objects.

Anyone with experience in the matter who can comment would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jon.

Comment: It is impossible to tell as it is difficult to tell what you require and what to achieve.

Comment: I think he wants to know if his class should contain an `fstream` instance variable for the real file that is used by all member functions over the lifetime of the instance, or if he should create a separate `fstream` instance for each function call. Not sure if he wants to re-open the `path` in each function tho, a rewording of the question may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have nailed the two issues right on the head.  Generally the most efficient approach is to keep the files around (open) until you run the risk of running out of file descriptors.  On some systems file descriptors aren't recycled immediately, so you need to limit your use of descriptors by closing some files before you would run out.

If you know something more about which files are read/written more often, which are only read/written in large chunks, etc. you could close down those for which the penalty of having to open them again is relatively small.

Comment: This is not quite true. From the OP we have no idea of the reason for the class 'File' - It may just be filing away data into an appropriate file (for a particular hour), or may just be a way of ensuring that the `File` is a log file that is formatted in a certain way. We simply cannot answer the question without an explanation as to what the class is suppose to achieve.